# Analogue of 'workless' gem for Web Dynos on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, worker

I've recently found an awesome gem "workless", which allows to scale workers automatically and switch them off when they are not in usage. This is really nice, and have already saved me a lot of money. I'm just wondering, whether there are any ways to do the same for Web Dynos? To scale them up and down automatically, as the costs of running several web dynos continuously are pretty high.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598423/gems-services-for-autoscaling-herokus-dynos-and-workers

Comment: this is really great! however, seems to be little bit outdated